# How can i use INSERT as subquery in SELECT statement in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, insert

I want something like this. But I dont know the proper syntax.

```
select id from table1
where name = (insert into table1 (name) values ('value_abcd'))
```

Comment: I used 2 queries 1'st for insert into table1 & later select col1 from table1. But I want 1 query instead of 2..

Comment: An `INSERT` statement does not return any data, so there is no way you can use it as a subquery. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want something like this. But I dont know the proper syntax...{     select id from table1 where name= (insert into table1 (name) values ('value_abcd'));  }

Comment: From which language are you accessing the database?

Comment: you could use a trigger, if sqlight supports that function

Comment: writing for iPad app in Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a table with an autoincrementing primary key, and you want to know its value after you have inserted a record.

In SQL, you can use the [last_insert_rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) function:

```
INSERT INTO table1(name) VALUES('value_abcd');
SELECT last_insert_rowid();
```

However, in most cases you do not need to execute a separate `SELECT` query because most libraries have some function to return that value.
For example, SQLite's C API has the [sqlite3_last_insert_rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) function, and Android's [insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) function returns the ID directly.

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

```
WHERE something = somethingElse
```

`somethingElse` is an expression (so is `something`, but anyway). You are trying to use an `INSERT` statement as your `somethingElse`, but an `INSERT` statement doesn't return anything, so it can not be evaluated as an expression. Therefore, not only is whatever you're trying to invalid syntax, it also doesn't make any sense in a pseudo-code kind of way.

Perhaps if you can try to explain more clearly what it is you're trying to do (and why), someone will be able to suggest something for you.

Comment: Lets say, I have 2 Tables. Table2 has foreign key inherited from Table1,i.e (table1 -> table2). When user enter Information in table1, at the same time by selecting the key(foreign key for table2) from table1. How can insert data in table2?

Answer (score 0):

If `id` column of the table is set as identity, then in SQL

```
insert into table1(name) value('name')
select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

It will return last auto generated idetity value

If `id` column is not set as identity then in SQL

```
insert into table1(name)
output inserted.id
value('name')
```

It will return all `id` values inserted in a single statement.